# Access Android sharedPreferences from surfaceview

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

The code to access sharedpreferences is

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MySettings", 0);
    float X = settings.getFloat("myFloat", 0);
```

But **this only works from within an activity.**

How do I access it from else where?

Would a singleton be a good idea? And how would I set up and access this singleton.

I only want to store 4 floats, and this would have been great! But nothing is straight forward :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't there a getContext() method for SurfaceView?

```
getContext().getSharedPreference();
```

If that didn't work, you can load those vars in a singleton on start up, since there are only 4 of them.

```
public class ClassicSingleton {

   public float float1;
   public float float2;
   public float float3;
   public float float4;

   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep your right. I have the context passed in via the constructor method. So it is literally just `context.getSharedPreference();` Thanks!